# lookup column values in another column using regex to replace na

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a sample pandas data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'notes': pd.Series(['meth cook makes meth with purity of over 96%', 'meth cook is also called Heisenberg', 'meth cook has cancer', 'he is known as the best meth cook', 'Meth Dealer added chili powder to his batch', 'Meth Dealer learned to make the best meth', 'everyone goes to this Meth Dealer for best shot', 'girlfriend of the meth dealer died', 'this lawyer is a people pleasing person', 'cinnabon has now hired the lawyer as a baker', 'lawyer had to take off in the end', 'lawyer has a lot of connections who knows other guy']), 
'name': pd.Series([np.nan, 'Walter White', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Jessie Pinkman', np.nan, 'Saul Goodman', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]), 
'occupation': pd.Series(['meth cook', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'meth dealer', np.nan, np.nan, 'lawyer', np.nan, np.nan])
})


name                                    notes                                       occupation
NaN                     meth cook makes meth with purity of over 96%                meth cook   
Walter White            meth cook is also called Heisenberg                             NaN
NaN                     meth cook has cancer                                            NaN
NaN                     he is known as the best meth cook                               NaN
NaN                     Meth Dealer added chili powder to his batch                     NaN
NaN                     Meth Dealer learned to make the best meth                       NaN
Jessie Pinkman          everyone goes to this Meth Dealer for best shot             meth dealer
NaN                     girlfriend of the meth dealer died                              NaN
Saul Goodman            this lawyer is a people pleasing person                         NaN
NaN                     cinnabon has now hired the lawyer as a baker                  lawyer
NaN                     lawyer had to take off in the end                               NaN
NaN                     lawyer has a lot of connections who knows other guy             NaN
```

So, we have a total of three occupations:

```
pd.unique(df.occupation)

array(['meth cook', 'meth dealer', 'lawyer'], dtype=object)
```

I would like to lookup 'occupation' values in 'notes' column and if there exists a value in occupation already, replace any missing values for that row with the matching occupation. 
For example: on second row, occupation is missing. However, if we lookup 'notes' column for ('meth cook', 'meth dealer', 'lawyer'), we see that 'meth cook' exists in 'notes' column for second row. So, the missing occupation should be filled with 'meth cook'

I tried:

```
df.occupation[df.occupation.notnull()].apply(lambda x: df.occupation.str.extract('('+x+')'))
```

However, it does not give me the result I want. I would like to see the result as follows:

```
name                                    notes                                       occupation
NaN                     meth cook makes meth with purity of over 96%                meth cook   
Walter White            meth cook is also called Heisenberg                         meth cook
NaN                     meth cook has cancer                                        meth cook
NaN                     he is known as the best meth cook                           meth cook
NaN                     Meth Dealer added chili powder to his batch                 meth dealer
NaN                     Meth Dealer learned to make the best meth                   meth dealer
Jessie Pinkman          everyone goes to this Meth Dealer for best shot             meth dealer
NaN                     girlfriend of the meth dealer died                          meth dealer
Saul Goodman            this lawyer is a people pleasing person                       lawyer
NaN                     cinnabon has now hired the lawyer as a baker                  lawyer
NaN                     lawyer had to take off in the end                             lawyer
NaN                     lawyer has a lot of connections who knows other guy           lawyer
```

Can someone give any inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with for loop by filling missing values from your `occupation` which is in `notes` using `str.contains` for subsetting your dataframe:

```
occ = pd.unique(df.occupation[df.occupation.notnull()])

for pa in occ:
    subset = df.notes.str.contains(pa, case=False)
    df.occupation[subset] = df.occupation[subset].fillna(pa)


In [40]: df
Out[40]:
              name                                              notes    occupation
0              NaN       meth cook makes meth with purity of over 96%     meth cook
1     Walter White                meth cook is also called Heisenberg     meth cook
2              NaN                               meth cook has cancer     meth cook
3              NaN                  he is known as the best meth cook     meth cook
4              NaN        Meth Dealer added chili powder to his batch   meth dealer
5              NaN          Meth Dealer learned to make the best meth   meth dealer
6   Jessie Pinkman    everyone goes to this Meth Dealer for best shot   meth dealer
7              NaN                 girlfriend of the meth dealer died   meth dealer
8     Saul Goodman            this lawyer is a people pleasing person        lawyer
9              NaN       cinnabon has now hired the lawyer as a baker        lawyer
10             NaN                  lawyer had to take off in the end        lawyer
11             NaN  lawyer has a lot of connections who knows othe...        lawyer
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I did the following while waiting:  `occupation_list = list(pd.unique(df.occupation))
occupation_list = [x for x in occupation_list if str(x) != 'nan']
df['occupation'].fillna(df.loc[pd.isnull(df.occupation)]['notes'].apply(lambda x: filter(lambda occ: re.search(occ.lower(), x.lower()), occupation_list)[0]), inplace = True)
` and that seemed to work. However, when I apply it to my actual data set, I get the following error: list out of index. Am not sure how filter() works.